# String to method

Tags: c#

Being able to create javascript code on the fly is pretty cool. 
That is by using

```
HtmlPage.Window.Eval("alert('Hello World')");
```

But is there a way to do the same thing, with a C# method? Lets say something like

```
void MethodEval("MessageBox.Show('Hello World')");
```

Is it even possible, without having to recompile your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it right now. The [ag DLR (Silverlight Dynamic Languages Runtime)](http://www.codeplex.com/sdlsdk) can host javascript.

While Javascript cannot be hosted with the DLR outside the browser Ruby and Python can. Here's an example of a C# snippet using the [DLR](http://dlr.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Docs%20and%20specs&referringTitle=Home) and hosting a piece of Python of code to demonstrate.

```
using IronPython.Hosting;

PythonEngine pythonEngine = new PythonEngine();
string script = @"import clr 
 clr.AddReference(""System.Windows.Forms"") 
 import System.Windows.Forms as WinForms 
 WinForms.MessageBox.Show(""Hello"", ""Hello World"")";
pythonEngine.Execute(script);
```

Comment: Where is PythonEngine located in? I have added 
IronPython.dll
IronPython.Modules.dll
IronRuby.dll
IronRuby.Libraries.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.Core.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.ExtensionAttribute.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.Silverlight.dll

and still says am missing a namespace

Answer (score 3):

It's possible using tricks posted by others.  **However, it's usually a very bad idea.**

.Net code typically runs in a more trusted context than a javascript browser sandbox, and has access to a much richer, and therefore potentially damaging, api.

Instead you use the System.Addin namespace to provide a very strict interface for extensions, plugins, and the like.  If you're just trying to use a more "fluid" or functional programming environment you can use fun features like lamdba expressions and closures to pass functionality around internally.

Comment: Makes sense, but still think it would of been a cool feature. Imaging a silverlight application with just a few lines of code, and when it starts, it downloads the additional codes (string), parses it and runs it.

Comment: You can download additional strongly typed assemblies in silverlight now.

Comment: @Joel: If you're using CodeDom, you can compile and run in a separate appdomain with limited trust.  I don't see a problem.  See http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=418038 for a sample.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but a little more tricky, using Microsoft's .NET framework.

The C# compiler is part of the base runtime, so you can compile an in-memory assembly, and execute code in there on the fly.

Here is a [good MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/digitalnetbizz/archive/2004/01/31/create-assembly-in-memory-and-run-it.aspx) describing the basic process.

I have used this before to make a scripting engine for a C# project.  With a little work wrapping this, you can make this quite easy to use.  An open source project I've worked on has a project dedicated to this:  [Pluto.Scripting](http://trac.assembla.com/plugintoolkit/browser/trunk/Pluto.Scripting)

We had examples and tests in that project which show dynamic compilation and execution of C#, VB.NET, and Boo.

Comment: So basically you will need to have the c# compiler? How about on a web based application?

Comment: @Fredrick: The C# compiler is part of the framework.  It always exists if you can run IL.  On a web-application, though, I'd be very wary of using this, since it could lead to allowing bad code to be injected easily.

Comment: @Reed, actually on a asp.net application, if you are using a Web Site project (as apposed to a Web Project) you get that for free.  All code in App_Code is dynamically compiled in...not that I recommend that.

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, but you can also do this manually, there, using the BCL, if you wish :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/), you can use its [interpreter](http://boo.codehaus.org/Scripting+with+the+Boo.Lang.Interpreter+API).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I kept on getting an error "unexpected indent" so changing the code to

```
PythonEngine pythonEngine = new PythonEngine();
            string script  = @"import clr; clr.AddReference(""System.Windows"");"; 
                   script += @"import System.Windows as Wins;";
                   script += @"Wins.MessageBox.Show(""Hello World"");";
            pythonEngine.Execute(script);
```

Worked! interesting... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this feature ? Shouldnt your code know its paths and include that logic ? If you cant forsee such use cases - then perhaps its not needed. The only real benefit is it opens an opportunity to be abused and attacked. It sounds like your in directly creating a potential for an exploit - its a shame because managed runtimes like Java/CLR dont allow code injection but you are bringing all that goodness back in...

Comment: I just wanted to know if its possible to do it in c#.